# Ridiculously slow mongoDB query on small collection in simple but big database

Tags: mongodb, optimization, query-optimization, pymongo, database

So I have a super simple database in mongoDB with a few collections:

```
> show collections
Aggregates <-- count: 92
Users <-- count: 68222
Pages <-- count: 1728288847, about 1.1TB
system.indexes
```

The `Aggregates` collection is an aggregate of the `Pages` collection, and each document looks like this:

```
> db.Aggregates.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("50f237126ba71610eab3aaa5"),
        "daily_total_pages" : 16929799,
        "day" : 21,
        "month" : 9,
        "year" : 2011
}
```

Very simple. However, let's try and get the total page loads by adding all 92 days `daily page loads` together:

```
>>> def get_total():
...     start = datetime.now()
...     print sum([x['daily_total_pages'] for x in c.Aggregates.find()])
...     end = datetime.now()
...     print (end-start).seconds
...
>>> get_total()
1728288847
43
```

**43 seconds?!??!??!?!**

Those 92 aggregate results are tiny! I might as well just store them in a text file, this is crazy.

Or are they tiny? How big are they on disk according to mongo?

```
> db.Aggregates.stats()
{
        "ns" : "c.AggregateResults",
        "count" : 92,
        "size" : 460250104,
        "avgObjSize" : 5002718.521739131,
        "storageSize" : 729464832,
        "numExtents" : 7,
        "nindexes" : 2,
        "lastExtentSize" : 355647488,
        "paddingFactor" : 1.0690000000000066,
        "systemFlags" : 1,
        "userFlags" : 0,
        "totalIndexSize" : 16352,
        "indexSizes" : {
                "_id_" : 8176,
                "date_1" : 8176
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

**438 megabytes total for those tiny daily numbers?** Each one is approximately 280 bytes, so they should be a maximum of 25~30kb total. So the storage is huge and the query is super slow. Is it possible it could be fragmented on disk? I created the aggregates after inserting the documents into the the full `Pages` collection.

Anyone have any insights into this madness? :O

---

Edit: Solved with more specific find() query by Jared. The video below that Sammaye provided also gives some very interesting storage insights.

---

Edit 2: So I found out that using sys.getsizeof() is a *really* unreliable method of finding out your document's sizes since it doesn't recurse down any trees. So actually my docs were quite large, and the best thing to do was to use find({}, {'daily_page_loads'}) as a more specific query!

Comment: How much free disk space do you have on your server? Mongo is _very_ aggressive in how it allocates disk space. Read this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/storage/#faq-disk-size Very soon Mongo will create a 2GB file for every new database.  Also you might have journaling turned on which also can take up a ton of space.

Comment: I've got 508GB of disk space left, processor is running at 99% idle, and 32gb ram, basically none of which is being used :(

Comment: I have no idea then. You're right it's a small collection and should run fast. I don't know Python, but my last guess would be the call you are making runs Aggregates.find() more than once and that multiplies the run time.

Comment: Hmm mongo says that the average object size of actually 4mb not the 280 bytes you think (avgObjSize) which would make 300-odd megs I would say the rest is possibly pre-allocation of future extents and fragmentation. As for running slow, can you show us an iostat -x for that period that you query?

Comment: Also is the aggregate collection created fresh by dropping it first? If not and it is actually done by emptying the table and then refilling it that could account for the hefty fragmentation you might have.

Comment: OK here is the `iostat -x 2`: http://pastebin.com/hdahC5pG . This time the query ran in 6 seconds - faster but still very slow.

Comment: Do you have any documentation dropping it first then creating it new? Does that defrag the disk?

Comment: This is really to do with MongoDBs internals and how it handles the namesapces, I havent got a doc page on it but basically this presentation might help here: http://www.10gen.com/presentations/storage-engine-internals basically deleting a collection just puts all of that space to free space which is easier to reuse while deleting records puts then to a delete buckets list, which if you change the size of your records can mean most of those are not renewable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `avgObjSize` is out of line with the 280 byte estimate. It's saying your objects are averaging around 5MB and `storageSize` is near 1GB. If you're memory-constrained running a query that needs to access all 1GB of file would cause lots of page faults.

Have you tried [compacting](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/compact/)?

```
db.runCommand({compact: 'Aggregates'})
```

or [repairing](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/)?

```
db.repairDatabase()
```

If that doesn't work try pulling back just those fields needed for the sum rather than pulling the whole document. It may be that those documents are actually 5MB and the time is spent pulling data over the wire.

```
def get_total():
    start = datetime.now()
    print sum([x['daily_total_pages'] for x in c.Aggregates.find({}, {"daily_total_pages": 1})])
    end = datetime.now()
    print (end-start).seconds
```

Comment: OK so I ran the compacting and its the same amount of time. Trying repairDatabase now

Comment: > db.repairDatabase()
{
        "errmsg" : "Cannot repair database c having size: 1262054539264 (bytes) because free disk space is: 545048477696 (bytes)",
        "ok" : 0
}
>

Comment: After the compact did the collection stats change significantly?

Comment: After the compact, the collection is fractionally smaller

Comment: Holy crap! that new query sped it up bigtime! One sec, gonna try it across my whole cluster

Comment: Great! So the question is why? Clearly there's a lot more in that doc than 280 bytes. To diagnose, instead of summing you could print each doc using the original `find()`.

Comment: OK so now I can query uber fast (bows to Jared, god of query) but yeah, there simply isnt that much data, each doc is literally 280 bytes. Looping through each document and getting sys.getsizeof() for each one is simply 280. Ho-hum.

Comment: Any chance your data is hosted at MongoLab? If so, write us at support@mongolab.com with host, port, and name of db and I'd be happy to help dig in to the deeper mystery.

Comment: Haha nope, but thanks for the suggestion! :) My 10+TB of site stats could be rather pricey :P Looks like a very cool service though~ you should present it at the NYC Big Data Meetup!

Comment: Ah, I'm betting `getsizeof()` isn't recursing down the entire nested structure of the documents. What does the print technique yield?

Comment: You're actually correct. Dang. I went through and some are much larger. Boy do I feel silly now... But I think the main thing I learnt was using {},{'daily_page_loads':1} makes a much faster query!