# MongoDB small collection Query very slow

Tags: performance, mongodb

I have a 33MB collection with around 33k items in it. This has been working perfectly for the past month and the queries were responsive and no slow queries. The collection have all the required indexes, and normally the response is almost instant(1-2ms)

Today I spotted that there was a major query queue and the requests were just not getting processed. The Oplog was filling up and just not clearing. After some searching I found the post below which suggest compacting and databaseRepair. I ran the repair and it fixed the problem. [Ridiculously slow mongoDB query on small collection in simple but big database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385696/ridiculously-slow-mongodb-query-on-small-collection-in-simple-but-big-database)

My question is what could have gone wrong with the collection and how did databaseRepair fix the problem? Is there a way for me to ensure this does not happen again?

Comment: How often do you remove and update the collection's documents and what do you update them with?

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that could be an issue here, but ultimately if a repair/compact solved things for you it suggests storage related issues.  Here are a few suggestions to follow up on:

**Disk performance:**  Ensure that your disks are performing properly and that you do not have bad sectors.  If part of your disk is damaged it could have spiked access times and you may run into this again.  You may want to test your RAM modules as well.

**Fragmentation:**  Without knowing your write profile it's hard to say, but your collections and indexes could have fragmented all over your storage system.  Running repair will have rebuilt them and brought them back into a more contiguous form, allowing your disk access times to be much faster, especially if you're using mechanical disks and are going to disk for a lot of data.

If this was the issue then you may want to adjust your paddingFactor to reduce the frequency of this in the future, especially if your updates are growing the size of your documents over time.  (Assuming you're using MMAPv1 storage).

**Page faults:**  I'm assuming you may have brought the system down to do the repair, which may have reset your memory/working set.  You might want to monitor for hard page faults that indicate that your queries are being bottlenecked by IO rather than being served by your in-memory working set.  If this is consistently the case, your application behavior may change unexpectedly as data gets pushed in and out of memory, and you may need to add more RAM.